# Mean re-arrivals for interarrival process with arbitrary IID distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My academic background on inter-arrival processes is nearly 40 years old, so I've forgotten a few things.

Anyway, given a distribution for inter arrival time I'm looking for the mean number of recurrences in time T - i.e. the mean of $n | \sum(x_1..x_n) < T \land \sum(x_1..x_{n+1}) > T)$. For the right class this is is probably a homework question; if I knew which class I could just look up the textbook :-(

For my purposes I want to be able to calculate numeric values, given a value for T and an empirical distribution for the pdf - i.e. interpolating from a histogram of measured values. It's obviously straightforward to do this with Monte Carlo methods, but it would be much more satisfying if I knew the proper answer. (and probably more computationally efficient, which counts in the end application)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - some additional searching and the triggering of a few fading neurons yielded the insight that it's a renewal process. If anyone comes across this post, see e.g. "Introduction to Probability Models", Sheldon Ross, Chapter 7 "Renewal Theory and its Applications".

In particular I was looking for the *renewal function* $N(t)$, i.e. the number of arrivals up to time $t$. It turns out that:

$E(N(t)) = \sum_1^\infty F_n(t)$

where $F_1(t)$ is the CDF, and if $f(t)$ is the PDF, $F_{i+1}(t) = \int_0^\infty F(t-y)f(y) dy$

(i.e. $F_n(t)$ is the CDF for the sum of $n$ inter-arrival times)

So basically given the PDF in numerical array form, I can do a series of convolutions to get $F_1$, $F_2$ etc., add 10 or 20 of them together, and use interpolation to get good predictions when the result is a small number. (when it's a large number, it's fairly well approximated by $t/\mu$ where $\mu$ is the mean inter-arrival time)